# Plotly Express rename legend/variable

Tags: python, plot, rename, legend, plotly-express

How to rename the variables (i.e. "fiber","protein","potass") in the legend and also in the hover text? [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRkoJ.png)

```
fig=px.scatter(df,x=["fiber","protein","potass"],y="rating",trendline="ols",
           labels={"rating":"Rating (%)"},
           hover_name="name")
```

These three variables have their own columns, which is why the x data is a list.

I've tried editing the `labels` but it didn't change anything in the plot.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the legend item names as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63633975/12135727).

I am not clear with the labels issue you are encountering. Could you share the code for that if possible or clarify more about the problem.

All I could find was the [official doc](https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/#automatic-labelling-with-plotly-express). I may be able to help you if you can provide sample code for your problem.